# VBA code to write worksheet to tab delimited file fails

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following VBA code

```
sub aemaketxtfile(className As String, rosterFileHandle As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim cellContent As String
Dim gradebookContent As String
With Worksheets(className).UsedRange
    gradebookContent = "  % seating" & vbCrLf
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
      For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
        cellContent = "a"
        cellContent = .Cells(i, j).Value
        gradebookContent = gradebookContent & cellContent & vbTab
       ' gradebookContent = gradebookContent & vbCrLf & Join$(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(i).Value)), vbTab)
    Next
       gradebookContent = gradebookContent & vbCrLf
    Next
    End With

 Open Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "seating_chart.xlsm", rosterFileHandle) For Output As #1
 'Open rosterFileHandle For Output As #1
     Print #1, Mid$(gradebookContent, Len(vbCrLf) + 1)
Close #1
End Sub

Sub makeALLtxt()
Call aemaketxtfile("all students", "rosterAllStudents.txt")
End Sub
```

Everytime I run it I get an error: "Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number

I've used this code in another Excel document without any issues.  I don't understand why it's not working here.

If I comment out the first `Open Replace ....` and uncomment the second, I can get things to work, but I'm not happy with that because some time Excel seems to save the file to a random directory.

Comment: Have you checked the path?

Comment: Try replacing `Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "seating_chart.xlsm", rosterFileHandle)` with `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & rosterFileHandle`.  I think this gives the result you seek without relying on the name of ThisWorkbook.

Comment: @TonyDallimore If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "seating_chart.xlsm", rosterFileHandle)
```

with

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & rosterFileHandle
```

I think this gives the result you seek without relying on the name of ThisWorkbook